# Using jquery to toggle between different function and not getting resumed where it left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code of the first function shows three different divs on specific Interval 5seconds (div1,div2,div3). 
 
The code of the second function used to stop showing the divs.
while showing div2 , I clicked the link to stop at that point it got stopped.
But after that i clicked it again and it shows div1 (its getting toggling fine) but i would like to continue next action which was to show div3.

> ***Jquery Code :***

```
$(function() {

 var IntervalId;

 function first_function() {
 var counter = 0,
 divs = $('#div1,#div2,#div3');
 function showDiv () {
           divs.hide() // hide all divs
          .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }) 
          .show('fast'); // and show it
          counter++;
 }; 
 showDiv();     
 IntervalId = setInterval(showDiv, 5000);
 }; 

 function second_function(){  
  clearInterval(IntervalId); 
 }  

 $("#link1").toggle(
 first_function,second_function
 );

});
```

> ***Html Code :***

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link1">Toggle</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the initialization of counter outside first_function():

```
$(function() {

 var IntervalId;
 var counter = 0,

 function first_function() {
 divs = $('#div1,#div2,#div3');
 ...
```

In your example, every time you call first_function(), the counter is set back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Have fun with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var divFunctions = [];
  var $divs = $('#div1,#div2,#div3');

  $divs.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    divFunctions.push(function() {
      return function() {
        $divs.not($this).hide();
        $this.show("fast")
      };
    }());
  });

  var $toggle_button = $("#link1");
  $toggle_button.toggle.apply($toggle_button, divFunctions);
});
</script>

<body>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link1">Toggle</a>

  <div id='div1' style="display:none;">content1</div>
  <div id='div2' style="display:none;">content2</div>
  <div id='div3' style="display:none;">content3</div>
</body>
```